# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on TeamCity build agent in AWS

Tags: docker, teamcity, docker-aws

I've got build agent machine on Amazon Linux AMI. It has docker container `jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest`. I can see build agent in TeamCity panel.

When I'm trying to run build with docker build/push commands I'm getting this error

`Cannot login to registry docker.io (new); cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?; exit code 1 (Step: docker build (Docker))`

What's wrong with `teamcity-agent`?

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is with `teamcity-agent`? What happens if you just try to run `docker ps` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest` will be running as a user that does not have docker permissions. Either the user that runs the commands in this image needs to be added to the group docker, or via ACLs be given permission to the docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. Note that this is `root`-equivalent.